# Python print output to variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to assign print output to some string variable

```
print "Cell:", nei, "from the neighbour list of the Cell:",cell,"does not exist"
```

Could you please advice?

Comment: Why not simply using `=`? Why are you complicating your life?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are `nei` and `cell` variables? Do they have values? Are you trying to print them?

Comment: yes nei and cell are variables

Comment: `my_var = ' '.join(["Cell:", str(nei), "from the neighbour list of the Cell:", str(cell), "does not exist"]) + '\n'` is equivalent

Answer (score 3):

Use simple string concatenation:

```
variable = "Cell: " + str(nei) + " from the neighbour list of the Cell: " + str(cell) + " does not exist"
```

or string formatting:

```
variable = "Cell: {0} from the neighbour list of the Cell: {1} does not exist".format(nei, cell)
```

Comment: The variables may not be strings necessarily.

Comment: this will fail if nei or cell are not strings, which could be the case depending on the coordinates used

Answer (score 0):

It's not the way Python works. If you do **NOT** have enough reason, simpliy use `=`. 
But if you insist, you may do like this.(Again, it's very unnecessary)

```
    def printf(*args):
        together = ''.join(map(str, args))    # avoid the arg is not str
        print together
        return together
    x = printf("Cell:", nei, "from the neighbour list of the Cell:",cell,"does not exist")
```

If you are only try to join things into a string, there are many ways you can do:

- `x = ''.join(("Cell:", str(nei), "from the neighbour list of the Cell:",str(cell),"does not exist"))`
- `x = "Cell:%s from the neighbour list of the Cell:%s"%(nei, cell)`
- `x = "Cell:{} from the neighbour list of the Cell:{}".format(nei, cell)`
- `x = "Cell:{key_nei} from the neighbour list of the Cell:{key_cell}".format({'key_nei':nei, 'key_cell':cell})`

have a look at [python's string formating](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) and [python's str](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Comment: @ussrback Not very clear about your question. If want to write print output into a file, Have a look at [python redirect output to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python). If you want to write to a csv file with csv module, you need to control it by yourself